# How to add external go package in hyperledger chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

How to add external go package in hyperledger chaincode.
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoKZd.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best option to go is to have your external package vendored inside the chaincode, you need to `cd` into your chaincode package and run:

```
govendor init
govendor fetch path_to_external_package
```

You can find more about go vendoring [here](https://github.com/kardianos/govendor).

Comment: Thanks Artem Barger

Comment: where is the "chaincode package"? I'm starting from the fabric examples

Comment: I tried inside chaincode and chaincode-docker-devmode, no luck